# Using a list of attributes in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4

i'm currently using pyqt4 to make a sudoku gui and I'm facing a problem while trying to iterate through the attributes of the mainwindow object.

So basically, I want to use the setTabOrder method so I've to apply it this way :

```
self.setTabOrder(self.textboxA, self.textboxB) 
self.setTabOrder(self.textboxB, self.textboxC) 
self.setTabOrder(self.textboxC, self.textboxD)
```

I've already done this (it is perfectly working)

```
            self.centralwidget.setTabOrder(self.case0_0, self.case0_1)
```

but I have a loooooot of textboxes to go through so I wanted to iterate through them using the vars() function like this :

```
    for a, b in vars(self).items():
        if type(b) == QtGui.QTextEdit and a != 'case8_8':
            name = list(a)

            if a[6] != '8':
                name[6] = str(int(a[6])+1)
            else:
                name[4] = str(int(a[4])+1)
                name[6] = '0'

            name = ''.join(name)
            suivant = vars(self)[name]
            self.centralwidget.setTabOrder(self.b, self.suivant)
```

it doesn't work and gives me this error :

```
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'b'
```

b is obviously pointing to the same object as case0_0 ( I printed it to make sure) :

```
<PyQt4.QtGui.QTextEdit object at 0x000001F5043DC708>
<PyQt4.QtGui.QTextEdit object at 0x000001F5043DC708>
```

Then my question is how can I can use a list of attributes in such a way ?

Comment: See my answer. Also, any specific reason you're not using QObject.findChildren() instead of itterating through class fields?

Answer (score 0):

`b` is already an object of `QTextEdit` type in context you're trying to call it, also, it's a local variable in that context, not class attribute, so that `self.b` call is useless and produces that error.

Same goes for `suivant`.

Try changing that `setTabOrder` call to:

```py
self.centralwidget.setTabOrder(b, suivant)
```

P.S. you should really use `QObject.findChildren()` method.